# Regex - numeric only with negatives allowed, but only one leading zero

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to find a way to allow numeric only numbers that can also be negative, but also allow only one leading zero.
Goal Examples: 0, 12345, -555
Bad Examples: -0, 01235, -012

I have the following so far, but cant seem to work in the negative character properly.  If I type - first nothing can be typed afterwards, but it should allow 1-9:
/^([-0]|[1-9]\d*)$/

Tried this as well, but no luck:
/^[-]?(0|[1-9]\d*)$/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

----updated code----
//can type in a 0, but not a hypen for negative.  If I rotate the ?:0|-? to be ?:-|0? I can then type in the hypen, but not a zero.

function(evt) {

```
            evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            let expect = evt.target.value.toString().trim() + evt.key.toString();
           
            if (!/^(?:0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)$/.test(expect)) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            } else {
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Can you clarify One Leading Zero for me?
You say you want to allow one leading zero, but in your bad examples, you have 01235 which contains one leading zero.

Comment: Sure.  you should be able to use zero as a value, but only zero.  It cant be -0 or 0 followed by a number is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's keep it simple:

```
/^(?:0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Start of string
(?:     # Start of non-capturing group
 0      # Match either a zero (and nothing else)
|       # or
 -?     # an optional -
 [1-9]  # a digit between 1 and 9
 [0-9]* # 0 or more further digits
)       # End of group
$       # End of string
```

Comment: Thanks much Tim!!  Worked great.....thanks as well John.  I appreciate both of your help in getting me straightened out here.

Comment: Tim - adding this into a keypress event to validate seems to have one issue still.  IF, a - is used to begin things it is preventing anything after that from being entered (e.g if you use 0 or - you cannot type after that).  It should allow for negative numbers as -1 or -1234, etc.  Not sure if there needs to be an additional tweak?

Comment: Yes, a `-` by itself is not a valid match, so if you check the entire regex on ongoing input, that is expected. You could do something like `/^(?:0|-?(?!0)[0-9]*)$/`, but then a solitary `-` will remain a valid input. I don't think you can avoid that if you only use a single regex to validate ongoing input.

Comment: Thanks much Tim that indeed is what I need and can handle for the solitary -.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/ltuB4y/1))

```
\b0\b|-?\b(?!^0)[1-9]+[0-9]*\b
```

Comment: Careful, `[^0]` will match anything (except 0), so also `Ä` or `%` etc.. A negative lookahead assertion might be better suited.

Comment: And `\b` will not work as expected before a `-` since `-` is not a "word" character

Comment: Done some fixes based on @TimPietzcker input